# Java static hashMap returns duplicates

Tags: java, static, hashmap, iterator

I actually do not know what the problem may be so I titled it according to my 
own intuition.
This simple program was meant to be a demonstration of static variables and methods along with the hashMap demo.

---

**Retrieved duplicate values are what can't cope with, why are there duplicates in a HashMap at all?
Shouldn't iteration through static hashMap after each adding identify possible previous duplicates and functionally remove them?**

Then I tried to call *removeDups* method to manually delete them, this attempt failed too.

Code:

```
public class Registration {

    public String name;
    public static int count;

    public static HashMap<Integer, Registration> listOfUsers = new HashMap<>();

    public static ArrayList finalList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Registration() {

    }

    public Registration(String name) {

        this.name = name;
        count++;
    }

    public static int getRegistered() {
        return count;
    }

    public void putUserInDB(String name) {
        listOfUsers.put(count, new Registration(name));

        removeDups();
        printUsers();

    }

    private static void removeDups() {

        for (Integer key1 : listOfUsers.keySet()) {
            for (Integer key2 : listOfUsers.keySet()) {
                if (!key1.toString().equals(key2.toString())) {
                    Registration x = listOfUsers.get(key1);
                    Registration y = listOfUsers.get(key2);
                    if (x == y) {
                        listOfUsers.remove(key2);
                    }

                }

            }
        }

    }

    private void printUsers() {
        for (HashMap.Entry<Integer, Registration> e : listOfUsers.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(e.getKey());
            System.out.println(e.getValue());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + this.name;
    }
```

---

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[]args) {

        Registration r = new Registration();

        r.putUserInDB("Olga");
        r.putUserInDB("Maria");
        r.putUserInDB("Tatiana");

        System.out.println("No of registrations: " + r.getRegistered());
        System.out.println("__________________________________________");

        r.putUserInDB("Anastasia");
        r.putUserInDB("Aleksandra");

        System.out.println("No of registrations: " + r.getRegistered());
        System.out.println("__________________________________________");

        r.putUserInDB("Nikolai");
        r.putUserInDB("Aleksei");

        System.out.println("No of registrations: " + r.getRegistered());    
    }
```

OUTPUT:

```
0
```

Name: Olga
0
Name: Olga
1
Name: Maria
0
Name: Olga
1
Name: Maria
2
Name: Tatiana
No of registrations: 3

Comment: You don't have duplicates. You are just printing it over and over when calling `printUsers()` from the constructor.

Comment: Map has unique keys, while it seems to me that you want unique values...

Comment: And anyway, what is your key? Static field? Have you considered synchronisation? And why do you even need a map instead of just having a set, the count would be just `set.size()`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `removeDups` method is supposed to remove duplicate values from the `HashMap`. A `HashMap` can contain duplicate values. Your specific `HashMap` has unique `Integer` keys, and `Registration` values, which can be considered to be duplicate if they have the same name.

That said, `removeDups()` is written badly. It compares the values with `==` instead of `equals`, which means it will never remove anything. In addition you have to override `equals` in `Registration` class if you want it to ever return `true`.

After you fix those issues, you may get `ConcurrentModificationException`, since you should not `remove` from a `Collection` while iterating over the `Collection` (unless you use an explicit `Iterator` and use the `Iterator`'s `remove()` method).

EDIT:

As Guy commented, your `putUserInDB()` method also calls `printUsers()`, which prints all the users that were added. Therefore some users will be printed multiple times.